# run method in Vue-Js only once

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I want to add random number (from 0 to price of item) to one of data properties in vue js but only once when page is loaded, but i cant use **mounted** and **computed** because i wanna send parameter to the function...
i tried this way but its not work (this function run with every change on the page, and every time give me another random number)..

its my code

```
{{getRandomNumber(item)}}
```

```
data(){
   return {
     getRandomNum = true,
     moneyOfSellItems = 0,
   }
},
methods: {
 getRandomNumber(item) {
  if (this.getRandomNum) {
   this.moneyOfSellItems = Math.floor(Math.random() * `${item.price}`) + 2;
   return this.moneyOfSellItems;
   this.getRandomNum = false;
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time your component will re-render, the number will change. And with your method (having a boolean to set to false to prevent re-render), the number will show the fist time and the other times, nothing will show at all because when `this.getRandomNum` is false, then `getRandomNumber()` doesn't return anything. In your specific case, it will keep returning a different number because your line

```
this.getRandomNum = false;
```

will never run as it's after a `return` statement;

I suggest having a `randomNum` in your data set to null and have `getRandomNumber()` return that number if it's set or set it to a random number

```
data(){
   return {
     randomNum: null
   }
},
methods: {
 getRandomNumber(item) {
  if (this.randomNum === null) {
   this.randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * `${item.price}`) + 2;
  }
  return this.randomNum;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to call your function inside mounted function? I mean, something like this:

```js
mounted(){
 this.getRandomNumber(item);
}
```

Hope this could help

Comment: item is undefined here I'm guessing his template looks something like `<li v-for="item of item">Price : {{ getRandomNumber(item) }}</li>`

Comment: Ok, but I think there is a better way to do this, but now I understand, maybe with the ready() lifecycle function

Comment: same thing, you can't access the item from a lifecycle function. One way would be to inject a random number on the item as soon as the array loads its content